# Qu'est-ce que « disoit » et « seroit » ?

Tags: temps-grammatical, histoire, conjugaison

Je pense que il s'agit des verbes *dire* et *être*, respectivement.

J'ai vu la proposition hypothétique :

> S’il ne disoit verité, il seroit gehainé.

Qu'est-ce que *disoit* et *seroit* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit de français du XV<sup>e</sup> siècle.

Beaucoup de ***oi*** ont été transformés en ***ai*** lors de la [réforme de l'orthographe de 1835](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9forme_de_l%27orthographe_fran%C3%A7aise_de_1835).

Aujourd'hui on écrirait:

> S'il ne disait pas la vérité, il serait torturé.

*Gehainé* a évolué en français moderne en *gêné*, au sens nettement affaibli...