# « Quotidiennement » ou « Journalier »

Tags: choix-de-mot, adjectifs

D'après le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/quotidiennement/65805), la définition de **quotidiennement** étant :

> Qui se fait chaque jour : Il fait sa promenade quotidienne avec son
>   chien.

Mais la [définition](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/journalier_journali%C3%A8re/45037) de **journalier / journalière** étant la suivante:

> Qui se fait, se renouvelle chaque jour : Travail journalier.

Je ne comprend donc vraiment pas la différence entre *« Quotidiennement »* et *« Journalier »*, les deux adjectifs ayant l'air d'exprimer la répétition d'une action chaque jour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Non locuteur natif du français.)

Premièrement, il y une faute. C'est quotidien.nne et journalier.ère les adjectifs à comparer et pas quotidiennement et journalier.ère ce premier étant un adverbe.

Faisant du googling fournit :

[(1)](http://www.lemotdujour.com/francais/quotidien-journalier/)

> Doit-on parler d’un travail quotidien, ou d’un travail journalier, par
>   exemple? Ces deux adjectifs signifient « Qui a lieu chaque jour ». Et
>   pourtant, on parle du « pain quotidien », et non du « pain journalier
>   », d’un « travailleur journalier » et non du « travailleur quotidien
>   ». Il me semble, mais c’est plutôt de l’ordre du ressenti, qu’il y a
>   dans « quotidien » l’idée de fatalité, d’obligation, ou du moins de
>   régularité, qu’il n’y a pas dans « journalier ». Si vous avez des
>   précisions, des désaccords à apporter à cette Subtilité du Mercredi,
>   n’hésitez pas.
>
> 1/ Quotidien : qui se reproduit chaque jour, avec l’idée de
>   régularité, de similitude. Il y a dans « quotidien » l’idée de
>   routine, qui peut être lassante, alors qu’il me semble que la surprise
>   est permise dans « journalier ».
>
> 2/ Journalier : qui se produit chaque jour, mais qui peut être
>   différent chaque jour. Cette nuance me vient du fait que journalier
>   peut signifier, mais dans le registre littéraire, « Qui change d’un
>   jour à l’autre, changeant, capricieux ».
>
> Cette différence de sens est, et c’est toujours personnel, très
>   intéressante, car elle touche à la frontière très fluctuante entre le
>   hasard et le destin. Entre ceux qui croient que le destin existe, et
>   que tout est écrit d’avance, et les autres qui perçoivent la vie comme
>   une succession de hasards…finalement, le lien entre les deux
>   doctrines, c’est peut-être une affaire de confiance, de lâcher-prise,
>   c’est l’idée qu’on n’a pas toutes les cartes, et que ce n’est pas si
>   grave.

[(2)](http://portail.atilf.fr/cgi-bin/getobject_?a.102:38./var/artfla/encyclopedie/textdata/IMAGE/)

> QUOTIDIEN, JOURNALIER, (Synonymes.) ces deux mots ont, selon leur
>   étymologie, la même signification, mais ils ne s'emploient pas
>   indifféremment. On dit, une fievre quotidienne, & ce seroit mal dit,
>   une fievre journaliere; il semble que notre pain quotidien soit un mot
>   consacré dans l'oraison dominicale; notre pain de chaque jour, comme
>   parlent quelques traducteurs du Nouveau Testament, est une phrase que
>   l'usage n'a pas adoptée. Pain journalier ne se dit pas mieux que
>   fievre journaliere; mais on dit, le mouvement journalier du ciel; la
>   révolution journaliere du premier mobile; & non pas le mouvement
>   quotidien, la révolution quotidienne; on dit encore, l'expérience
>   journaliere: ce sont des bisarreries de l'usage. Homme journalier, &
>   armes journalieres se disent, mais ce n'est qu'au figuré, & on ne
>   regarde ici journalier que dans le propre.

Du coup, voyant [seroit](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29263/quest-ce-que-disoit-et-seroit), je crois que ce lemme vient d'un ancien dictionnaire.

Citant @StéphaneGimenez : *Édité de 1751 à 1772 par [Diderot et d'Alembert](https://books.google.fr/books?id=i0E_AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=quotidien%20ou%20journalier&source=bl&ots=YeNUaTe1xz&sig=ACfU3U2Y5GricYYoxgKRne4Cwxweeff_Jw&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3w-LUtvfgAhXBxoUKHeRMA7c4ChDoATAHegQIBRAB#v=onepage&q=quotidien%20ou%20journalier&f=false), et il est pourtant toujours utile dans bien des cas.*

---

Il y a [lemme exhaustif](https://books.google.fr/books?id=KIQGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA312&lpg=PA312&dq=quotidien%20ou%20journalier&source=bl&ots=T_8H__trBf&sig=ACfU3U3wLc9cxp94vB8JSpUZ8nLE8IaiSQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj3w-LUtvfgAhXBxoUKHeRMA7c4ChDoATAFegQIABAB#v=onepage&q=quotidien%20ou%20journalier&f=false) dans le dictionnaire : Nouveau dictionnaire universel des synonymes de la langue française (M. Guizot (François) 1809).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Deux questions similaires dans des forums linguistiques :

http://www.forum.french-linguistics.co.uk/forum/topics/journalier-versus-quotidien

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/journalier-vs-quotidien.2404805/?hl=fr

Comment: édité de 1751 à 1772 par Diderot et d'Alembert… et il est pourtant toujours utile dans bien des cas.